# thymeleaf vs thymeleaf-spring4 dependency

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, thymeleaf

Question is simple, what is the difference between the above dependencies? Does the first one enough for a springboot app or the second contains something special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifact [`thymeleaf`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf) is the Core library.

Artifact [`thymeleaf-spring4`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring) allows to integrate Thymeleaf with the Spring Framework, especially (but not only) Spring MVC. Btw there are several Thymeleaf integration packages for different Spring versions are available at the moment:
thymeleaf-spring3, thymeleaf-spring4, thymeleaf-spring5.

Information from [thymeleaf-spring official documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html):

> Thymeleaf offers a set of Spring integrations that allow you to use it as a fully-featured substitute for JSP in Spring MVC applications.
>
> These integrations will allow you to:
>
> - Make the mapped methods in your Spring MVC @Controller objects forward to templates managed by Thymeleaf, exactly like you do with JSPs.
> - Use Spring Expression Language (Spring EL) instead of OGNL in your templates.
> - Create forms in your templates that are completely integrated with your form-backing beans and result bindings, including the use of property editors, conversion services and validation error handling.
> - Display internationalization messages from message files managed by Spring (through the usual MessageSource objects).
> - Resolve your templates using Spring’s own resource resolution mechanisms.

If you use Spring Boot, you can just use the [spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.0.0.RELEASE) dependency. It already contains the above two dependencies as well as some others.